# Need help with AC relay wiring

Tags: ac, relay, wiring

Got the following relay Taiss/AC 220V (YJ2N-LY AC 220V)
A picture and a wiring diagram are below.
Given:

- AC 230v constant L input
- AC 230v signal L input
- N input
  ,

How should I wire the relay to get 2 L and N outputs (2*[L+N] wires), one of which is based on NC logic and another one is NO?

[image: wiring]

[image: relay]

Source: http://www.yjele.com/en/soft/20210217144608300.pdf

Product image: https://www.desertcart.com/products/137738157-taiss-ac-220-v-coil-electromagnetic-power-relay-5-a-2-dpt-8-pins-2-no-2-nc-my-2-nj-hh-52-p-with-yjf-08-a-e-socket-base-quality-assurance-for-2-years-yj-2-n-gs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4A8H7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. As specified.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f20kGI.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A more typical wiring solution.*

Comment: Thank you. I was confused by (-) and (+) for 7 and 8 (not a real expect in these things).

Comment: I didn't pay any attention to those as your relay has an AC coil. The base is standard for a variety of relay types. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: One follow-up question if I may. In AC world, am I allowed to only use connectors [2] and [4] for L OUT (both NC and NO respectively) but connect N OUT directly to N IN, without passing it through the relay? Thank you.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Appreciate it. No more questions. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

According to the drawing you show, terminals 5 and 6 are the common contacts, where you would connect the power input.  Terminals 1 and 2 are the Normally Closed contacts, and 3 and 4 are the Normally Open contacts.

Terminals 7 and 8 are the relay coil (control input).